# Get term weight in node object for ordering with EntityFieldQuery

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

Is it posiible to expose taxonomy term weight in node object ?

I need to sort nodes using EntityFieldQuery by term reference field, but weight is not exposed to node object so i can say for example

```
->fieldOrderBy('field_custom_terms', 'weight', 'ASC');
```

and sort nodes by weight of terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can only order on actual field values, the term weight would require a JOIN to a non-field table and EFQ is not capable of doing that.

You will have to create a manual SQL query to do this. Note that Drupal by default maintains the node <-> term associations in the taxonomy_index table, that one is easier and more reliable to query than a field data table.